# Runtime error <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'unicode' object is not callable

Tags: python, arcpy

I'm working on a script to replace a layer datasource, and I'm getting an error I cannot figure out.

When I run the following code in a python window inside ArcMap, I get a "Runtime error : 'unicode' object is not callable"

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument ("CURRENT")
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
     if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE"):
         if lyr.dataSource (r"N:\3_PLANNING\6_GIS\GIS Data\INDIANA GIS\Indiana_County.mdb\Boundaries\Indianacounty_shp"):
             lyr.replaceDataSource (r"N:\3_PLANNING\6_GIS\GIS Data\Indiana_County_Database_201201.gdb", "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE", r"N:\3_PLANNING\6_GIS\GIS Data\Indiana_County_Database_201201.gdb\Boundaries\County_Boundary")
```

Problem is, I'm not very good at python yet, and I'm not sure what the unicode object is that the error is referring to.

Comment: Can you please post the full stack trace?  Is this all the code?  What are you using to create the python script?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by full stack trace. Yes, it is all the code. I'm just using the python window in ArcGIS and IDLE.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue was:

```
if lyr.dataSource (r"N:\3_PLANNING\6_GIS\GIS Data\INDIANA GIS\Indiana_County.mdb\Boundaries\Indianacounty_shp"):
```

it should be:

```
if lyr.dataSource == "N:\3_PLANNING\6_GIS\GIS Data\INDIANA GIS\Indiana_County.mdb\Boundaries\Indianacounty_shp":
```